# Print a list of items separated by commas but with the word "and" before the last item

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I've been working on this for two days. This is what the assignment states:

> Say you have a list value like this: `listToPrint = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']` Write a program that prints a list with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with "and" inserted before the last item. For example, the above list would print `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`. But your program should be able to work with any list not just the one shown above. Because of this, you will need to use a loop in case the list to print is shorter or longer than the above list.

This is what I have thus far:

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input("a, b, and c ")
    if newWord == "":
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? The`while` loop you are using above should do what you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your response Rick.  That's what I thought, but that seems like too simple a fix.  So if I was going to add to the list where would I insert it, and how? Would I simply keep adding or subtracting from the input?  Shouldn't the list stay in a global list somewhere? I'm fairly new at this so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I understand it's difficult to ask the right questions as a beginner, but I'm also having difficulty understanding the problem you're having as a result. The input line and the line `listToPrint.append(newWord)` executes each time the loop happens. They are inside the body of the while loop. That body is executed each time until `break` is encountered.

Comment: With your code as written, `listToPrint` is already a global variable of the type `list`. You can confirm this by adding the line `print(type(listToPrint))`.

Comment: Thanks again Rick.  This is what the assignment states "Say you have a list value like this:
listToPrint = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
Write a program that prints a list with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with andinserted before the last item. For example, the above list would print 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your program should be able to work with any list not just the one shown above.  Because of this, you will need to use a loop in case the list to print is shorter or longer than the above list." I've worked on it for two days now.

Comment: Ah ha. Got it. Why don't you update your question with some of that made a little bit more explicit? Provide the required input, required output, and the code you have tried (which you've already provided).

Comment: How do I update my question? Start a new one?

Comment: Click edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, but be careful if this is for school.  Your instructor will frown on you if any of the things I have done below are using features or techniques that haven't yet been covered.

```
listToPrint = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def list_to_string(L, sep = '', last_sep = None):
    if last _sep is None:
        return sep.join(L)
    else:
        return sep.join(L[:-1]) + last_sep + L[-1]

print(list_to_string(listToPrint, sep = ', ', last_sep = ', and '))
```

Here's a bit more of a beginner version:

```
listToPrint = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_length = len(listToPrint)

result = ""
count = 0
for item in listToPrint:
    count = count + 1
    if count == list_length:
        result = result + "and " + item
    else:
        result = result + item + ", "
```

This one doesn't work with only one item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown appears to be solving a different problem than what your assignment wants you to do. The assignment is focused on `print`ing the values from a provided `list`, while your code is all about `input`ing items from the user and putting them into a list. It could make sense to do one and then the other, but for the assignment that you've given in the comments, the `input` code is completely irrelevant.

Here's how I'd solve that assignment (probably with code that you don't understand yet):

```
print("{}, and {}".format(", ".join(list_to_print[:-1]), list_to_print[-1]))
```

A more "novice friendly" approach would look more like this:

```
for item in list_to_print[:-1]:
    print(item, end=', ')
print('and', list_to_print[-1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this one worked.                                                                                                                                              for item in list_to_print[:-1]:
            print(item, end=', ')
            print('and', list_to_print[-1])

Answer (score -1):

Beginner Version:

```
x = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

print("'", end='')

for i in range(len(x)-2):

    print(x[i], end=', ')

print(str(x[-2])+' and '+str(x[-1]),end='')

print("'")
```

Output: `'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'`

Answer (score -1):

```
#printing the first element sep. so the list works     
print(listToPrint[0], end="") 

for i in range(1, len(listToPrint)-1):

    print("," + listToPrint[i], end="") #this prints the middle elements

if(len(listToPrint) > 1):

    print( " and " + listToPrint[-1], end="")
```